# How to get the one right city name by lan lng from google api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

With this query http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.6723855,139.75891482 I can get a list of different places by the coordinates, but I want to get only the right city name. Is there a way to get only ONE city name "Tokyo"? (Not the UchisaiwaichЕЌ,Chiyoda-ku and so on) 
As I see the right one has "**colloquial_area**" type, but is there a way to select only this one?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use result_type parameter to get only colloquial_area item in the response:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.6723855%2C139.75891482&result_type=colloquial_area&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This will return 'Tokyo, Japan'.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to use it with place_id ChIJ45IxpAtkGGAR3_hG0anDMg0 ? as there is no result at all if I try something like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&result_type=colloquial_area&place_id=ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA&key=...

Comment: No, place ID is a unique place identifier, the result_type is not allowed when you specify a place ID.

Comment: Thanks. I just want to the the city name from place_id + geocode, but there is a list of place names, and it is very strange that there is no way to get the right city name from api. Just ['city']=>"Tokyo". And it looks like in some places there is no colloquial_area, so no way to select the city name. It is very irritating.